# Proof of Nested Interval Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Let $I_{n}=[a_{n},b_{n}]$ for every $n \in \mathbb N$ and $I_1 \supseteq I_2 \supseteq \dots$. Then $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty I_n\neq \phi$. Is the following proof correct?

The sequence $a_1 \le a_2 \le a_3 \le \dots$ is bounded above and since $a_n\le b_n$ for every $n\in \mathbb N$ it follows that we have the sequence $b_1 \ge b_2 \ge b_3 \ge \dots$ is bounded below by $a_1$ [for any $n$ we have $b_n \ge a_n \ge a_1$]. Hence the set $\{a_1, a_2, \dots\}$ is bounded above and has a supremum in $\mathbb R$, suppose $a$. Now the sequence $-b_1\le -b_2 \le \dots$ is bounded above by $-a_1$. Hence the set $\{-b_1,-b_2,\dots\}$ is bounded above and a supremum exists in $\mathbb R$, suppose $-b$. We claim that $b$ is the infimum of the sequence $b_1 \ge b_2 \ge b_3 \ge \dots$. If not, then there exists some $b_n$ such that $b\ge b_n$ and thus $-b\le -b_n$ contradicting that $-b$ is an upper bound. Thus $a_1 \le a_2 \le \dots \le a \le b \le \dots \le b_2 \le b_1$. Indeed $[a,b]$ $\subseteq I_n\:\:\forall n \in \mathbb N$. If not, then for some $n \in \mathbb N$, we must have either $a \le a_n \le b \le b_n$ or $a_n \le a \le b_n \le b$. In both cases, we have a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to shuffle around with the opposite sequences and arguing for contradiction(s).

Since $[a_n,b_n] \supseteq [a_{n+1}, b_{n+1}]$ for every $n$, it follows that $(a_n)$ is monotone increasing and $(b_n)$ is monotone decreasing. By assumption there exist $\sup (a_n) =: a$ and $\inf (b_n) =: b$. Note that $a\leqslant b_n$ for every $n$, hence $a_n \leqslant a \leqslant b\leqslant b_n$ for every $n$.

Comment: Any monotone decreasing sequence has an infimum. Is that the assumption?

Comment: @UjjalMajumdar any nonempty subset bounded from below has infimum. Monotonicity is to ensure the last chain of inequalities holds for every $n$.

Comment: Can the proof of that infimum be derived in the same way that I did?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to the request of verification of your specific proof, but it contains a generalization of your statement, if you find it useful:

**Theorem:** Given a topological space $X$ and a sequence of closed, compact, and non empty subspaces $K_n\subseteq X$, with $n\in\mathbb N_{\geq 1}$, such that $K_n\supseteq K_{n+1}$ for all $n\in\mathbb N_{\geq 1}$, then: $$\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N_{\geq 1}}K_n\neq\emptyset$$

**Proof:** Let's set $A_n:=K_1\setminus K_n$. Then we have that:

1. Since $K_n$ is closed in $X\:\Longrightarrow\:K_n$ is closed in $K_1$, so $A_n$ is open in $K_1$ for all $n\geq 1$
2. $K_n\supseteq K_{n+1}\:\Longrightarrow\:A_n\subseteq A_{n+1}$ for all $n\geq 1$

Given an arbitrary $N\in\mathbb N_{\geq 1}$:
$$\bigcup_{n=1}^N A_n=A_N=K_1\setminus \underbrace{K_N}_{\neq\emptyset}\subsetneq K_1$$
This tells us that there's no finite union of $A_n$'s that cover $K_1$, which implies that: $$\bigcup_{n\geq 1}A_n\subsetneq K_1$$
Infact, otherwise, $\{A_n\}$ would be a open cover of $K_1$, and then, by compactness of $K_1$, we could extract a finite subcover, which we know to be impossible. So:
$$\bigcup_{n\geq 1}A_n=\bigcup_{n\geq 1}(K_1\setminus K_n)=K_1\setminus\left(\bigcap_{n\geq 1}K_n\right)\subsetneq K_1\:\Longrightarrow\:\bigcap_{n\geq 1}K_n\neq\emptyset$$
as we wanted.

Comment: Thank you for your kind gesture. I am aware of the generalisation, but am currently out of touch with topology for over a year. I have to brush it up a bit.